# Нужен ли перевод изображений в справке?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, справка

У нас в справке есть некоторые страницы с изображениями на английском. Следует ли их переводить?

Вот список этих изображений:

### [Доступ К Аналитике Сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

[image]
[image]

### [Проверенный Участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

[image]

### [Инструменты Модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

[image]
[image]

### [Принимать Описания Меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

[image]
[image]

### [Создавать Синонимы Меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

[image]

### [Постоянный Пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

[image]
[image]

### [Закрывать И Переоткрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

[image]

### [Видеть Голоса За Закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

[image]

### [Создавать Чаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)

[image]

### [Начинать Конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

[image]

### [Общие Сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

[image]

### [Как найти интересующие меня темы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### [Как добавлять и удалять данные о способах входа из моей учётной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

[image]
[image]

### [Как удалить свою учетную запись?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

[image]

### [Почему система просит меня подождать день или более перед тем, как задавать следующий вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

[image]

### [Привилегии - Голосовать за](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

#### Перевод изображений нужен!

---

На мой взгляд, есть два способа решения этой задачи.

1. Сообщество подготовит снимки и добавит к этому сообщению.
2. Я сам подготовлю снимки.

Первый вариант будет намного быстрее. Если появятся снимки с переведенным интерфейсом я очень быстро обновлю соответствующие статьи.

Answer (score 7):

А почему вообще эти блоки нужно делать изображениями?

Может лучше сделать их вёрсткой, чтобы нужные фразы сами подставлялись как на сайте?

Comment: А что значит "сделать их вёрсткой"?  (iframe имеется ввиду?) Картинки нужны, чтобы обводить элементы, стрелки к ним рисовать.

Comment: @jfs, нет, просто html-разметкой с css. Обвести тоже можно.

Comment: не просто сделать html-разметку, чтобы она соответствовала screenshot.

Comment: @jfs, ну а скриншот с чего по-твоему делается? Надо тот же блок и использовать. Только выделение прикрутить, но это не слишком сложно.

Comment: Вы хотите полную страницу, которую браузер получает, запихивать? А иначе, разметка поехать может. Вы можете показать конкретный пример для любого раздела? (я не говорю, что это невозможно в принципе, я говорю, что тяжело по сравнению со screenshot`ом это сделать)

Comment: @jfs, на мете виджетов нет. А так, могу.

Comment: @jfs, http://jsfiddle.net/qo3n8bwb/

Comment: хорошо получилось. Стоит рассмотреть эту идею.

Comment: @Qwertiy: отлично смотрится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо :) Но я почти ничего с ним не делал - только в 0 0 подвинул.

Comment: @Qwertiy: тут главное – отличная идея.

Answer (score 5):

**Это - общее сообщение. Можно добавить ваши переводы изображений сюда.**

---

### [Доступ К Аналитике Сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

Перевода пока нет

### [Проверенный Участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Перевода пока нет

### [Инструменты Модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Перевода пока нет

### [Принимать Описания Меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)

Перевода пока нет

### [Создавать Синонимы Меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Перевода пока нет

### [Постоянный Пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Перевода пока нет

### [Закрывать И Переоткрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [Видеть Голоса За Закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

Перевода пока нет

### [Создавать Чаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)

Перевода пока нет

### [Начинать Конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

[image: Начать конкурс диалог]

### [Общие Сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [Как найти интересующие меня темы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

Перевода пока нет

### [Как добавлять и удалять данные о способах входа из моей учётной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Перевода пока нет

### [Как удалить свою учетную запись?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

[image: help--deleting-account]

### [Почему система просит меня подождать день или более перед тем, как задавать следующий вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

[image: закладка голоса]

Comment: Нужно ли добавлять сюда картинки, которые уже локализованы или правильнее соответствующий пункт вовсе убрать из сообщения, чтобы он не отвлекал внимание?

Answer (score 0):

интересно, а нельзя ли как-то так сделать, чтобы в документации у картинки была какая-нить спец.ссылка на необходимый блок, из которого можно было бы автоматом делать картинку с нужным переводом, если он есть…

Comment: Не так часто делаются переводы документации. Всего раз на каждый локализованный сайт.

Comment: Это понятно, только и картинок может быть много, и каждую в таком случае нужно вырезать, … и вдруг дизайн поменялся, а так раз - запустил скрипт и все каринки перегенерились. Хотя вот, смотрю выше, еще инетересней идея - прямо разметку вставлять.